# Possible to run two instances of docker containers on one mysql database container?

Tags: mysql, docker

There are three containers

Container A : web server
Container B : replicate web server of Container A
Container Z : mysql datastore container for Container A

Can I run Container A and B at the same time using Container Z as mysql datastore? will it corrupt mysql data store?

Runtime of the containers below:

Container Z : 
docker run --name mysql_datastore -it busybox:mysql_datastore true

Container A:
docker run -it -p 80:80 --volumes-from mysql_datastore --name webservera -h webservera centos:webseverwithmysql /bin/bash

Container B :
docker run -it -p 81:81 --volumes-from mysql_datastore --name webserverb -h webserverb centos:webseverwithmysql /bin/bash

Comment: It's not clear what are the roots of this question. What is the relation between A, B and Z that may corrupt it?

Answer (score 9):

Hopefully one of these interpretations is correct.

### Can I run multiple mysql daemons in different containers that all share a single data volume?

No, each daemon needs a separate data directory to avoid conflicts. You could put multiple data directories in the shared volume, but the result of that is multiple completely separate databases. - [source](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/multiple-servers.html)

### Can I run multiple containers that *connect* to a single mysql database container?

Yes it is possible to allow multiple containers to connect to a single database container, but not by sharing volumes. Container Z will run the mysql daemon and other containers can connect to it via tcp sockets. The [official mysql repo](https://registry.hub.docker.com/_/mysql/) readme has steps to get started:

First start Container Z.

```
docker run --name some-mysql -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=mysecretpassword -d mysql
```

Then run other containers that you want to connect to the database with something like this:

```
docker run --name webservera --link some-mysql:mysql -d application-that-uses-mysql
```

[Docs for the `--link` flag](https://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockerlinks/). Container linking adds a hostfile entry for the link alias so you don't have to find the address manually. Your webserver's database configuration would look something like this

```
jdbc:mysql://address=(protocol=tcp)(host=mysql)(port=3306)(user=root)(password=mysecretpassword)
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: The --link flag is a deprecated legacy feature of Docker. A replacement would be user-defined networks. Check out https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/#/user-defined-networks