# Docker two containers stops each others

Tags: docker

[EDIT]: It seems to be a memory problem, I have increased the memory of the docker and now I can run the containers together. Thank you very much for all yours (very quickly) answers

I have created two containers(from 2 different images) with liferay instance on them, they are linked at the same postgres container but in a different DB.
The first container is published on port 8080 and the second on 8081.

Everything works fine except for one thing…if ContainerA is running and I start ContainerB, the ContainerA stops(and viceversa).

Searching on google I didn’t find nothing.
Someone has any idea? I am new about docker…port…etc.

As suggested I used the "docker logs ContainerName" after the Container stops, and this is the message:

> WARN  [elasticsearch[Terminatrix][scheduler][T#1]][jvm:173]
>   [Terminatrix] [gc][young][248][137] duration [5.9s], collections
>   [1]/[6.3s], total [5.9s]/[12s], memory [688.1mb]->[479.4mb]/[910.5mb],
>   all_pools {[young] [213.3mb]->[2.6mb]/[219.5mb]}{[survivor]
>   [33.9mb]->[34.3mb]/[61mb]}{[old] [440.8mb]->[442.4mb]/[683mb]}

Comment: What do the logs say?

Comment: Nothing, if I write "docker logs -f ContainerA" when ContainerB server is up it switch from log to prompt with no message and with "docker ps" I don't see ContainerA anymore (I see it with "docker ps -a")

Comment: Please edit your question and add [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). In other words, help us recreate your problem.

Comment: Edit with more info

Answer (score 0):

Yes its possible to connect to multiple container to one db container but shared volume should be different.

It explained in this thread

[Possible to run two instances of docker containers on one mysql database container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27791297/possible-to-run-two-instances-of-docker-containers-on-one-mysql-database-contain)